# Using multiple IoC containers with SimpleIoC to achieve separation of concerns: Is it possible and does it make sense?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, ioc-container

**tl;dr**

Is it possible with SimpleIoC to use multiple IoC containers in order to achieve a separation of the management of objects related to the GUI (ViewModels, etc) and the objects related to the backend code?

**/tl;dr**

Through getting started with WPF using MvvmLight, I have come in contact with SimpleIoc, which I use as the ViewModelLocator. In my project I now have a class called `ViewModelLocator` that is responsible for returning the ViewModels as well as a DataService bound to IDataService. For this I followed the great [Big Mvvm Template at CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/768427/The-big-MVVM-Template).

I am now getting ready to hook up my GUI with my "backend", which contains code for controlling external hardware. I also would like to use SimpleIoc to instantiate the objects, responsible for controlling my hardware. However these are obviously not ViewModels and therefore the ViewModelLocator is not the ideal IoC instance/location to register these classes.

So my question is, whether it is possible and makes sense to create a second instance of SimpleIoC for these objects, or if there is another way to achieve a clean separation between the management of instances for the GUI and those for the backend objects? I am still very much new to the concept of IoCs (and C# as well) so I would be very grateful for any code examples. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use multiple containers, this will make your life a pain, as the `ViewModelLocator` needs to resolve the ViewModels, and the ViewModels have dependencies on your business/domain services and/or repositories etc.

All you need is to allow your `ViewModelLocator` to be passed a delegate method for resolving, this way your `ViewModelLocator` is independent of an IoC container, i.e.

```
// default implementation can use Activator.CreateInstance that instantiate parameterless viewmodels
// You'll override it to use IoC
private Func<Type, object> resolver = null;
public static void SetResolverFactory(Func<Type, object> factoryMethod) 
{
    if(factoryMethod!=null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(factoryMethod));

    resolver = factoryMethod;
}

// inside your ViewModelLocator
protected T Resolve<T>() 
{
    return (T)resolver(typeof(T));
}
```

Then inside your bootstrapper just set the resolver to SimpleIoC or whatever you use.

For example

```
// get the singleton instance and set it or just use a static method that wraps around the singleton instance
ViewModelLocator.Instance.SetResolverFactory( type => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance(type));
```

and your viewmodels will be resolved by SimpleIoC. If you decide to switch to antoher IoC container, you just call the resolve method of your new IoC container, no need to do any changes in `ViewModelLocator`.